# Thymeleaf for each loop, having trouble getting the correct output

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm using SpringBoot MVC,

I have a Thymeleaf forloop going on. and i'm trying to figure out the correct output.

I have these divs with a class box. The Class box is what needs to be repeated over and over for each blog post.

i'm just stuck on where to put the div with class box at inside the forloop

```
    <div style="align-items: center" th:each="blogPosts : ${BlogPosts}">
    <h3 style="align-items: center"  th:text="${blogPosts.title}"></h3>
    <p style="align-items: center"  th:text="${blogPosts.description}"><p/>


<div class="box" style="width:100%">
    <div class="glass"></div>
    <div class="content" style="padding:0; margin:0;">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It looks like I figured it out. sorry guys!

Comment: <div class="box" style="width:100%" th:each="blogPosts : ${BlogPosts}">
        <div class="glass" th:text="${blogPosts.title}"></div>
        <div class="content" style="padding:0; margin:0;"  th:text="${blogPosts.description}">
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this question will be to other people as it is. But if you think it will be, you might put your solution in an answer when it lets you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay So It looks like I figured it out, sorry guys.

I'm new to thymeleaf. "th:each" will be taking over the current div and repeating the current div.

```
    <div class="box" style="width:100%" th:each="blogPosts : ${BlogPosts}">
    <div class="glass" th:text="${blogPosts.title}"></div>
    <div class="content" style="padding:0; margin:0;"  th:text="${blogPosts.description}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in a hecktic moment asking this question.

If you find this page and have similar thinking. Let me explain my code

```
     'th:each="blogPost : ${BlogPosts}"'
```

here we have two parameters. parameter 1 blogPost, is what thymeleaf is going to look for within your block. The second parameter is         '${BlogPosts}' this is the variable we are grabbing from in our controller.

Thanks

'

```
                                                                                    <p style="align-items: center"  th:text="${blogPosts.description}"><p/>


<div class="box" style="width:100%">
    <div class="glass"></div>
    <div class="content" style="padding:0; margin:0;">

    </div>

 </div>

   '
```